# Execute owl-carousel script after jQuery replaceWith() method (DOM elements replacement)

Tags: jquery, replacewith, owl-carousel-2

[Here is my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yyeq7hv/2/)

On document ready I want to:

1. Replace 3 divs (with classes:' one', 'two', 'three'')  with 3 divs (each one with the same 
   class 'smilling') with jQuery replaceWith() method,
2. Run the owl-carousel plugin.

I don't know why but although dom elements replacement **does** go successful  owl-carousel does not load.. Any suggestions? Why do I want to do this? It has something to do with MediaQueries...

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.super").replaceWith('<div class="smilling item"></div><div class="smilling item"></div><div class="smilling item"></div>');

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                    loop:false,
                    nav:true,
                    items:1 
                });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are replacing the `.super` class using `replaceWith()`. What you want to do is replace all child's of the `.super` class.

Instead call `replaceWith()` on `.item` and instead of three new div's only spawn one new div.

Something like this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("div.item").replaceWith('<div class="smilling item"></div>');

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop:false,
                nav:true,
                items:1 
            });

});
```